# cin gets a number and convert it. How to not close console after hitting enter?

Tags: c++, window

I've started learning C++. Here's my simple problem. I have a code:

```
int main() {
  int number;
  cout << "Input number: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << "here is hex = 0x" 
       << hex << number << endl;
}
```

I'm using Visual C++. I think the point of this program is easy, user enters some number and program converts it to hex value. But when I enter some number and hit enter, console window just closes. How to display hex inside console window?

Comment: Try running it from a normal console window.

Comment: @Anto I went to "debug" folder inside my project, I double clicked on my .exe file and effect was the same.

Comment: @smogg: Open the run dialog, type in `cmd.exe`, and then type in the full path of the .exe for your program and hit enter (I think, haven't used Windows for long)

Comment: @smogg - Anto means that you need to open a CMD shell, navigate to the directory containing your program, and execute it from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include `cstdlib` and add `system("PAUSE");` to your main:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int number;
  cout << "Input number: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << "here is hex = 0x" 
       << hex << number << endl;
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

That's it, happy programming ;-)

Instead of pausing you could also use `getch()`  from `conio.h`. This waits for a key, so the console window wont close until you hit any key...

---

From the comments, to get `PI` in C++ just add the following to your header:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
```

and you'll have access to the variable `M_PI` :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's it! And what You said is true ;) Beginning of learning every language gives me a lot of fun and that's the time I love the most (and also hate cause of problems like this one ;)). But there will be days I'll laugh as hell about this question. I'll ask here to not spam with another stupid question: how to get PI in C++? Do I need to define some variable or its built-in somewhere? I'm building program which will calculate are of circle! God, I'm so cool!

Comment: Thank You for your answers. I've included "cmath" and defined "Something" (I don't understand this line yet) but it gives me an error of undefined M_PI when I try to use it.